# Grails Application doesn't deploy in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, grails

I have my grails app converted to maven project. In my pom.xml I have the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My application starts with **grails run-app** but when I build war through **maven compile install** , deployment fails in tomcat with below error

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing Grails: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app runs with run-app, you should be able to build with grails war and deploy that way instead of using Maven.

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/war.html

> By default the war command creates a web application archive (WAR) file using the application name and version number. The war command is different from most commands since it runs in the production environment by default instead of development, but like any script the environment can be specified using the standard convention:

Comment: In my origanization I am  under a compulsion to use maven as our project is deployed using jenkins which uses maven

Comment: Jenkins can use any build system you like. Our own Jenkins has a mix of Maven, Gradle and Grails. There is even a Grails plugin for Jenkins.  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Grails+Plugin